# Find point covered by all given circles

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given is n (n <= 1000) circles ((x;y), r) where (x;y) = coordinates of circle center, r = radius. x, y, r <= 10^6. x, y, r, can be real numbers.

The problem is to find point(x;y) covered by all circles, or determine that there are no such points. Coordinates of point can be real numbers too.

No ideas how to do it, could anyone help, please?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/ might be more appropriate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on another stack exchange site.

Comment: @Jarod42 mathoverflow is for problems that mathematicians want help with.  mathematics would be appropriate, but so is stackoverflow/algorithm, since an algorithm is wanted.

Comment: Pick the circle with a smallest radius.  If there is such a point then it is in that circle.  Work up through increasing radii to look for overlaps, or no overlap.  No overlap means no such point exists.  Use any overlap to reduce the possible area that holds the specific point.

Comment: What do you mean by "find point(x;y)"? There may be 0 or infinite number of such points. Do you mean the points with given coordinates `(x, y)`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by circle you mean what mathematicians would call a closed disk, there's an O(n²)-time algorithm with simple data structures.

For k from 1 to n, the algorithm finds a point in the intersection of the first k disks, assuming that such a point exists. Start with the center of the first disk. For each disk after the first, check whether the current point belongs to that disk. If so, great. If not, then either the intersection is empty or the intersection contains a point on the boundary of the current disk (the line segment from the current point to any point in the intersection of all of the disks must cross the boundary). In this case, find a new point by intersecting the boundary (a circle) with each of the previous disks, an easier 1D problem.

This might go even faster in expectation if we randomize the order of the disks, but I haven't worked out a proof. With n ≤ 1000, hopefully O(n²) is fast enough.

Sharir ("Intersection and Closest-Pair Problems for a Set of Planar Discs", 1985) may have given an O(n log² n)-time algorithm, but I can't tell from the abstract.

Comment: Great idea. Why do we need to start in the centre of a circle rather than starting by picking any circle and traversing the arcs on the circumference that are marked by intersections with the other circles, noting the count of the still-open ones?